# How to get the output of a maxpool layer in a pre-trained model in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I have a model that I trained. I wish to extract from the model the output of an intermediate maxpool layer. 
I tried the following

```py
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(BASE_DIR + LOG_DIR + '/model.ckpt.meta')
saver.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint(BASE_DIR + LOG_DIR))
sess.run("maxpool/maxpool",feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

here, `feed_dict` contains the placeholders and their contents for this run in a dictionary.

I keep getting the following error

```py
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_1_1' with dtype float and shape...
```

what can be the cause of this? I generated all of the placeholders and input them in the feed dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran in to a similar issue and it was frustrating. What got me around it was filling out the `name` field for every variable and operation that I wanted to call later. You also may need to add your `maxpool/maxpool` op to a collection with `tf.add_to_collection('name_for_maxpool_op', maxpool_op_handle)`. You can then restore the ops and named tensors with:

```py
# Restore from metagraph.
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(...)
sess = tf.Session()
saver = restore(sess, ...)
graph = sess.graph

# Restore your ops and tensors.
maxpool_op = tf.get_collection('name_for_maxpool_op')[0]  # returns a list, you want the first element
a_tensor = graph.get_tensor_by_name('tensor_name:0')  # need the :0 added to your name
```

Then you would build your `feed_dict` using your restored tensors. [More information can be found here](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/meta_graph). Also, as you mentioned in your comment, you need to pass the op itself to `sess.run`, not it's name:

```py
sess.run(maxpool_op, feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

You can access your tensors and ops from a restored metagraph even if you did not name them (to avoid retraining the model with new fancy tensor names, for instance), but it can be a bit of a pain. The names given to the tensors automatically are not always the most transparent. You can list the names of all variables in your graph with:

```py
print([v.name for v in tf.all_variables()])
```

You can hopefully find the name that you are looking for there and then restore that tensor using `graph.get_tensor_by_name` as described above.

Comment: I wanted to avoid retraining the model. So, I did a few things wrong. The first thing (Which does not appear here) is that I recreated the placeholders for the inputs instead of extracting them from the graph. so it should look like this : `input_name= = graph.get_tensor_by_name("Placeholder:0")`. The second thing I did wrong is inputing the name of the op instead of the op itself, so It should look like this `maxpool_op = graph.get_operation_by_name("maxpool/maxpool")` and then `sess.run(maxpool_op.outputs[0], feed_dict=feed_dict`
Somehow your answer pointed me in the right direction so 10x

Comment: Oh awesome, I'm glad it helped, although it looks like it could use improvement. Not wanting to retain makes sense. I'll modify my answer in a bit to reflect this. I know all the tensors are there, it can just be difficult to find them with their default names.